# How I can remove all hyperlinks in Word document using office.js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I need to remove all hyperlinks in Word document.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we need to select all document body. As a result, we have the range of selection. We should to set hyperlink for this range as undefined.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.body;
        var range = body.getRange();
        range.hyperlink = undefined;
        return context.sync();;
    });
```